# Cone $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ as a degenerate quadric

Tags: definition, inverse, quadratic-forms, quadrics

We can read here 
[quadric wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) that the  cone  $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ is a degenerate quadric but they don't define what is a degenerate quadric.

I know hat a quadric is non degenerate if the matrix associated to its quadratic form is invertible.

For the  cone  $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$, its matrix is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is $(1,1,-1)$ which is an invertible matrix.

Is there another definition of non degenerate quadric in the sense of wikipedia ?

EDIT
The relation between quadric and quadratic form could be also seen using the projective space of $R^3$.
Let $(x,y,z)\in P(R^4)$ and $(K,X,Y,Z)\in R^4$ homogeneous coordinates :
$x = X/K, y=Y/K ...$.
In that case a quadric of $R^3$ is a quadratic form on $P(R^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the matrix of this quadric is $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,0)$: you left out the linear and constant terms (which all happen to be zero in this case). The $3\times3$ matrix in your question is that of a *quadratic form* $q(x,y,z)$ that contains only second-degree terms. It does correspond to a quadric surface, but one that’s defined by the equation $q(x,y,z)=1$.